# How can I avoid package/character errors in (read) in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm getting some surprising errors when I try to input a string using `(read)`. Context: I'm building a mini language, with inputs deliminated using characters like {, }, :, etc.

Here's what happens, I run `(read)` and enter `{9.I:{8.II:hello}{8.III:hi}}` (an example input string from my mini language).

I then get 2 errors:

1:

`too many colons in "{8.II"`

2:

`Package HELLO}{8.III does not exist.`

It seems as though there's something extra going on in the `(read)` function that's tripping me up. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`read`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) is designed to read a valid Lisp S-expression. It's going to use Common Lisp's parser. If your language is sufficiently Lisp-like, you may be able to make it work for you, but given the example input you've shown, I doubt it's what you want.

You're probably looking for [`read-line`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm#read-line), which reads a single line of text as a string and does *not* perform any additional parsing on it.